# proof of principal value (1/x) is a distribution

Tags: real-analysis

I saw proof of 1.3 in https://www.math.purdue.edu/~arshak/F08/MA542/hw1.pdf

In final part of proof, if supp$\phi \subset [-a,a]$, then 
$$  \Bigl\lvert  p.v. \int \frac{\phi(x)}{x}dx \Bigl\rvert \leq 2a sup \lvert \phi' \rvert. $$

I have reached this, but why this implies distribution.
I know distribution is continuous linear functional.
Does boundedness need to $\phi$ not $\phi'$??

Comment: Remind yourself what "continuous" means for a linear functional that's to be a distribution.

Comment: @JohnDawkins sorry I got stucked.. How to show that this means continuity